# Comparing in Mini Java

Tags: java

So I have to write a code for binary tree in Java by following grammar rules for MiniJava. So far everything works except following line

```
if(node == null)
```

This obviously works well in JAVA but MiniJava is giving error. Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: Post error message you are facing so others with same error could find your question and potential answers. It may also help people willing to try answer your question.

Comment: Also can you explain what you mean by Mini Java? Any links we could use if we would like to download it and test your code?

Comment: It is a grammar that follows a little different Java rules. Here's the link
https://cs.fit.edu/~ryan/cse4251/mini_java_grammar.html
Also the error is 
ParseException: Encountered " "=" "= "" at line 88, column 17.
Was expecting one of:
")" ...
"[" ...
"." ...
"<" ...
"+" ...
"-" ...
"&&" ...
"*" ...
"." ...

Comment: At the bottom of your link it says "No literal null.". So it doesn't know what `null` is.

Comment: So what can I use instead of null?

Comment: A sentinel object might work. Create a `public static final [your class] EMPTY = [some empty construction]`, ensure you initialize variables to that, and then compare for it. That's probably what Mini Java is supposed to get you in the habit of doing, but... yuck. Seems very impractical.

Comment: Something tells me that you should be looking for inspiration in LinkedList example http://cs.fit.edu/~ryan/cse4251/minijava/LinkedList-java.html. Try to find how it handles first/last elements (it does it without nulls).

Comment: I think there's a problem with "==" as well since the error does state that and mentions nothing about "null"

Comment: @anonymousCoder Since this compiler is not widely used by million of people and doesn't have massive financial backing, I think it's far more likely the error message is just messed up. It's actually really hard to get good error messages in a compiler. If getting rid of the `null` fixes the error, you should send a bug report about the message to whoever maintains the language.

Comment: The thing is this is my assignment and it is due like in a couple of hours so this is why I was eager to solve this

Answer (score 0):

You can simulate a null check using

```
if (new Object().getClass().isInstance(x))
```